# Center \chapter (book class)

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters

Using the document class book, chapters headings (*Chaper 1*) are aligned on the left. How to center them?

Answer (score 9):

Using the `titlesec` package you can say:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

if both the heading and the title are to be centered, or

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

if only the heading must be centered.

If both the heading and the title are to be centered, the `sectsty` package provides another easy solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}   

\chapterfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

If, for some reason, no additional packages are to be used, the a redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` (for numbered chapters) and of `\@makeschapterhead` (for unnumbered chapters) will be needed (the original definitions for both commands can be found in `book.cls`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering\normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
         \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```