# Center All Chapter Titles in Dissertation

Tags: formatting

I can't seem to find a way to center all of my chapters (both Chapter X, and the title of the chapter)  without altering table of contents or causing errors rending the code unable to run

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

% packages
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% these make top, right, bottom margins about 1"
% and the left margin about 1.5"
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.75in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}



% this makes the chapters start with a 2" margin


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{0.75in}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont 
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@

  }}
\renewcommand*\@makeschapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{0.75in}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@

  }}
\makeatother



% makes page numbers appear
\pagestyle{plain} 

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: `s/raggedright/centering/` in your redefinitions of your chapterhead. And welcome, by the way.

Comment: If you copied the code from somewhere without knowing what it does, you will get into more trouble. [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) (<- Link to free ebook) is a good read to start with.

Comment: You could have a look at the following answers:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23859/134144  
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107282/134144

Comment: @Johannes_B: Not everyone is aware about the `/s/foo/bar` syntax...

Comment: Also, \@makechapterhead is for numbered chapters and \@makeschapterhead is for unnumbered chapters (like Table of Contents).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is use the `memoir` class and one already made chapter style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{bianchi} 
% try also "chappell", "dash", "demo2", "dowding" and "thatcher"
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\end{document}
```

You can also `\makechapterstyle` if none of these is good for you. Run texdoc memoir for more information.

There also a centered "Rejne" style in `fncychap` package. There are some commands for some customization. Run `texdoc fncychap` for more information.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap} 
\ChTitleAsIs
\ChNameAsIs
\ChRuleWidth{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\end{document}
```

Or you can use the `sectsty` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}\chapterfont{\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\end{document}
```

Or the `anonchap` package;

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{anonchap}
\simplechapter[\centering Chapter]
\renewcommand{\simplechapterdelim}{\par}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\end{document}
```

Or  the `titlesec` package as explained in [Center aligning chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13496/center-aligning-chapters).