# Edited book with Contributed chapters: first page layout

Tags: chapters, author

I am trying to typeset a book with contributed chapters. Each chapter has one corresponding author and number of co-authors with various affiliations.

In each chapter, I would like to have chapter title in centre followed by authors, affiliations, and contact information of corresponding author (alternatively, contact information may be given in footnote or at the end of chapter).

This will be followed by abstract, various headings/sections and at last references for the chapter.

So far, with the tips given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23858/center-chapter-book-class), I have been successful in getting what is shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{-50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \centering\normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \if@mainmatter
     \large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 1\p@
  \fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
 \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents{}
\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
  \chapter{Test chapter}
\textbf{Abstract:} \lipsum[23]
\textbf{Keywords:} Europe, Asia, Africa, America, Austrailia 
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[3-15]
\end{document}
```

What I want is something like this:[image: My requirements]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe is  time of run `texdoc combine` ?

Comment: I am a newbie and trying to collect the information on the go. BTW, I don't get it what you suggested.

Comment: You should have program named "texdoc" to search among the LaTeX manuals in you hard disk, so `texdoc combine` will show you the manual of the `combine` document class. I suspected  that is what you are looking for. Alternatively, you can find also the manual [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine).